# Plotly Sankey: How to sort target nodes

Tags: python, plotly

I'm currently trying my hands on the Sankey class of the plotly library of Python.
My problem is that when I specify targets of my links, the will always appear ordered by their values, instead of in the order of the values, for example:

```
labels = ["Source", "T1", "T2", "T3"]
source = [0, 0, 0]
target = [1, 2, 3]
value = [1, 3, 2]

node = dict(label=label)
link = dict(source=source, target=target, value=value)

fig = plotly.graph_objects.Figure(data=[plotly.graph_objects.Sankey(
    node = node,
    link = link
)])

fig.show()
```

I would like the targets to be displayed in the order T1, T2, T3, but I'm getting T2, T3, T1, because they are ordered by their value.
Is there any elegant way to get them ordered in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the x and y coordinates for the nodes to let it show up in the correct order. Look at the node position example [here](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/). (0,0) is top left of figure. One thing that is NOT there, but I learnt the hard way is that plotly does not like 0 and 1 for its coordinates (don't know why exactly). So, set the coordinates as 0.0001 and 0.999 instead or 0 and 1. Also, you will need to set arrangement to snap. See the updated code below.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

labels = ["Source", "T1", "T2", "T3"]
source = [0, 0, 0]
target = [1, 2, 3]
value = [1, 3, 2]
x=[0.0001,0.9999,0.9999,0.9999] ## Source is x=0 and others are x=1
y=[0.0001,0.0001,1/6,4/6]  ##Source is y=0, T1 starts at 0, T2 starts at fraction of total (6)...

node = dict(label=labels, x=x, y=y) 
link = dict(source=source, target=target, value=value)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(arrangement = "snap", ##Note - added snap
    node = node, link = link
)])
fig.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: This answered my question for the most part!  
Now I have just a little problem left, in my "real" data set, all the points are in the correct order, but the first and second, which are swapped. The first target is very small (2 out of 85) and the second one is bigger (13 out of 85). If I increase the size of the first target to 10, the order is correct, if I keep it smaller, they swap. Do you have any idea where this comes from?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a code that will fit all values. For your case, if values are say [2.13.15], keeping y as [0.0001, 0.0001, 1/3. 2/3] will work. If you know the `values` data, you can adjust `y` you will need to adjust the y a bit to see what will fit. A small value next to a big value (like in your case) usually causes the nodes to get snapped wrong. Keeping the bigger node further down (higher y value) usually forces it to stay below previous one. Hope this works for you